# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient Error but I have installed libmysqlclient-dev

Tags: gcc, compilation

I'm trying to compile this source code I have from a developers website that made his personal small MMO public, when trying to compile I get:

```
gcc -O -g -m32 -rdynamic -L/usr/lib/mysql -o server .obj/server.o .obj/io.o .obj/libload.o .obj/tool.o .obj/sleep.o .obj/log.o .obj/create.o .obj/notify.o .obj/skill.o .obj/do.o .obj/act.o .obj/player.o .obj/rdtsc.o .obj/los.o .obj/light.o .obj/map.o .obj/path.o .obj/error.o .obj/talk.o .obj/drdata.o .obj/death.o .obj/database.o .obj/see.o .obj/drvlib.o .obj/timer.o .obj/expire.o .obj/effect.o .obj/command.o .obj/date.o .obj/container.o .obj/store.o .obj/mem.o .obj/sector.o .obj/chat.o .obj/statistics.o .obj/mail.o .obj/player_driver.o .obj/clan.o .obj/lookup.o .obj/area.o .obj/task.o .obj/punish.o .obj/depot.o .obj/prof.o .obj/motd.o .obj/ignore.o .obj/tell.o .obj/clanlog.o .obj/respawn.o .obj/poison.o .obj/swear.o .obj/lab.o .obj/consistency.o .obj/btrace.o .obj/club.o .obj/teufel_pk.o .obj/questlog.o .obj/badip.o -lmysqlclient -lm -lz -ldl -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
```

I have ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS any information would be great thanks.

Edit:

```
ubuntu@va~/astonia3_server$ ls /usr/lib
lib/    lib32/  libx32/
ubuntu@va:~/astonia3_server$ ls /usr/lib/libmysql*
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/libmysql*: No such file or directory
ubuntu@va:~/astonia3_server$ ls /usr/lib64/libmysql*
ls: cannot access /usr/lib64/libmysql*: No such file or directory
```

Edit 2:

```
/usr/share/doc/libmysqlclient-dev
/usr/share/doc/libmysqlclient18
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.18
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.18.0.0
```

Comment: Show me the output of `ls /usr/lib/libmysql*` and `ls /usr/lib64/libmysql*`.

Comment: @drookie put it in the bottom of the question

Comment: No luck. Does the `find /usr -name libmysqlclient\*` give something ?

Comment: @drookie in the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because:

- you gave the linker wrong path to look for a shared library
- even with correct path you will get another error, because you are requesting to build 32-bit binaries, and you have 64-bit libraries.

Start building binaries matching your *arch*, either by issuing `-m64` or leaving the default. Or get the 32-bit shared libraries, if you need 32-bit binaries.

And this is more like SO question, rather than SF.

Comment: Any idea where I might get 32 bit libraries for mysql?

Comment: Why do you need them in the first place ? You have an *amd64* arch system. On whether to get them  -not sure, I'm not much of the Debian/Ubuntu fan. At least you can build a local 32-bit mysql in custom *prefix*, this is pretty easy. But may be there's a conventional way of getting them in Ubuntu. This is a matter of another question anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this source code I downloaded is just 32 bit I believe so I don't know if I can compile it for 64 bit.

Comment: You should suppose that it can by default, unless it's explicitly configured not to.